# Icon path in .desktop file

Tags: icons, .desktop, paths

On my desktop I have a .desktop file. If I type:

```
Icon=/home/ianbell/Pictures/myLogo.png
```

the icon of the .desktop file changes (the expected result).

But, if I type:

```
Icon=~/Pictures/myLogo.png
```

it doesn't work.

Isn't `~/` a shortcut for `/home/$USER`?

Comment: ~ is short for your home directory only in a shell.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: sorry, I fell asleep, I'm programming night and day   :-)

Comment: @IanBell Haha I know the feeling :)

Comment: /home/$USER won't work. It seems you are looking for - /home/$(whoami). See my comments below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### The use of paths in a .desktop file

In a `.desktop` file, you need to use *absolute* and *full* paths. Therefore `~` is not expanded.

This is a commonly made mistake :)

Exceptions concerning icons are a.o. described [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html):

> Icon to display in file manager, menus, etc. If the name is an
>   absolute path, the given file will be used. If the name is not an
>   absolute path, the algorithm described in the [Icon Theme
>   Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/icon-theme-spec/) will be used to locate the icon.

and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles):

> Icon field is the icon that should be used by the launcher and
>   represents the application. All icons that are under the directory
>   `/usr/share/pixmaps` don't need to have their full path specified, but
>   their filename without the extension. For example, if the icon file is
>   `/usr/share/pixmaps/wallch.png`, then the Icon field should be just
>   'wallch'. **All other icons should have their full path
>   specified.**

#### More information

In a `.desktop` file:

In the `Icon=` line, you *are* allowed to use spaces:

```
Icon=/home/jacob/Thema/icon/some folder/some icon.png
```

is fine.

***However***

In the `Exec=` line, you are *not* allowed to use spaces, unless in case of an *argument*. In all other cases, you need to quote the path steps with a space:

```
Exec=/home/jacob/Bureaublad/some folder/application
```

will fail, while

```
Exec="/home/jacob/Bureaublad/some folder/application"
```

or

```
Exec=/home/jacob/Bureaublad/"some folder"/application
```

will work fine

Comment: So how do I reference a path relative to "the users's home directory"?

Comment: Aaron Franke, you can use $(whoami) to get current username. I havent tried but this should work - for home dir for current user - /home/$(whoami).

Comment: I tried and it works Aaron.

Answer (score 5):

In short, `.desktop` file's `Icon=` path understands absolute paths, but not tilde expansion, because of the [specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) which defines how `.desktop` files are supposed to work.

### Tilde expansion

- Where you would see tilde (`~`) expansion to the `$HOME` environment variable is often for example in bash, which is the usual login shell you interact with on the command prompt
- bash, and other POSIX-compliant shells, do tilde-to-$HOME expansion consistent with [POSIX specification for **shells**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)

### .desktop files

- However, a `.desktop` file is not the same thing as a shell, it is a plain text configuration file so it would not necessarily work the same way, even if `.desktop` files and shells can both be found on Linux
- how a `.desktop`'s file is supposed to work, is defined in Freedesktop's [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)

Desktop Entry Specification, regarding `Icons`, says:

> If the name is an absolute path, the given file will be used.

This is why you were able to use absolute paths, since it is covered by the spec

> If the name is not an absolute path, the algorithm described in the [Icon Theme Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Standards/icon-theme-spec) will be used to locate the icon.

When we check the [Icon Theme Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Standards/icon-theme-spec), there is nothing that says it has to follow POSIX's tilde expansion at all.

### Summary

Thus, due to the Freedesktop specifications regarding `.desktop`'s `Icon=` setting, absolute paths are supported, but as you found, POSIX tilde-to-$HOME expansions are not.

Comment: `plasmashell` expands `~` in `Exec` just fine.