# permissions for .desktop ext

Tags: permissions, root

Unsuccessfully creating a `.desktop` file. In `usr/share/applications` user has r+w permissions. Do I need to change to rwx to create viable `.desktop`?

`sudo chmod u+x` for my user is not working (lacking operand after 'u+x').

Tried Freedesktop but it doesn't seem to cover this aspect...

Permissions are not my strong suit and I am new... very frustrated.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Foo
Comment=FooApp
Exec=/usr/share/applications/simi1.py
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pic.png
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
```

Idu how this is possible...my file is clearly in the dir

[screenshot of error and file ls info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiTFz.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default root should be the owner of the /usr/share/applications directory.

Are you able to use sudo to create and edit the file?

Either at a console :

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/myApp.desktop
```

Or maybe :

```
sudo gedit
```

then write the file and save it to the directory.

It is best practice to use sudo to make/edit files in directories with root permissions rather than change these permissions.

Alternatively, you could write the file in your home directory then use sudo to copy it to /usr/share/applications

```
sudo cp myApp.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Finally, if you want to use this myApp.desktop file as a shortcut on your desktop simply :

```
cp /usr/share/applications/myApp.desktop ~/Desktop/
```

Comment: yes I was able to cp to applications after writing with a text file...is this all that is necessary?  But how do I get the .desktop file (now residing in usr/../applications onto my desktop?

Comment: cp /usr/share/applications/myApp.desktop ~/Desktop/

Comment: what's the pt? I experimented....changed Name and the filename (saved properly ^O) I   ls -t  and got the old file name showing up....I want to break my freaking machine at this pt. srsly so whenever I write a .desktop into usr/../applications I can't edit or delete the file???

Comment: well I got it on the desktop...now it's missing the icon image and tells me it's untrusted....

Comment: apparently this is a artful aardvark bug ... ? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1687179

Comment: In case it interests you I'll just link a few articles on icon files ( in order of most useful to you ) :  https://askubuntu.com/a/722182/733893  https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/icons.html.en  https://askubuntu.com/a/435612/733893  Best of luck, and let me know how you go with getting icons working.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have root privileges to do this. Second you *don't* need executable permissions on the files in `/usr/share/applications`. A simple `ls -l` on the directory on my own machine shows this:

```
$ ls -l
total 2864
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5511 Dec 19 08:14 alacarte.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3417 Dec 17 15:21 assistant-qt5.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14329 Jan 23 13:37 bamf-2.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   296 Nov  2  2015 bastet.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6305 Jan 16  2017 bleachbit.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6333 Aug 30 13:38 bleachbit-root.desktop
...
```

Note that none of the above files are executable; in other words, files which are present in application directories like `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications` are not executable because no one is going to execute them. Files in your Desktop folder are executable so you can execute them but no one goes in `/usr/share/applications` to run an application.

Let's solve the first problem:

You can become root by running `sudo -i` and then entering your user password. Once you are root, you can create the desktop file with either

```
# gedit /usr/share/applications/[file].desktop
```

Or

```
# nano /usr/share/applications/[file].desktop
```

Now you can enter the contents of the file as you desire.

Comment: yes navigated through this...I have file.desktop saved in usr/../applications (I obv can't really edit it here) but the icon is not on my desktop anymore...

Comment: @meyeti Desktop icons are fetched from your `~/Desktop` folder not `/usr/share/applications`. Besides, what's preventing you from running `sudo -i` and then editing with gedit?

Comment: no protocol specified...

Comment: @meyeti Can you run `nano /usr/share/applications/[FILE]` instead of gedit?

Comment: i can get in...I'm denied permissions to save changes (so ^X  then Y  isn't viable) only ^Y then N to exit

Comment: @meyeti You need to run nano as root (`sudo nano ...` should work) and use ^O to save the file. You can also put the .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` instead as that doesn't require any additional privileges.

Comment: yup figured it was sudo -i ...that works (it clears the contents tho but I copy/pasted).  I prefer usr/../applications for now tho      but what about the 'substance' of the script I have Exec,Path,Icon,terminal variables in place but no file on my desktop to test run...

Comment: @meyeti Check this stackexchange question for the protocol error: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10441/264220. If you're on Wayland then switch to X as it doesn't allow for running GUI apps as root. If your issue is solved then close the question (and perhaps list the steps you took).

Comment: protocol err was solved.  it's 1) usr/../applications 2)sudo -i 3)nano file.desktop     U can't combine commands....   Now that that's out of the way, I'm still left with no 'tangible' file to run from my desktop...

Comment: wtf $ nano file1.desktop doesn't even show up in usr/share/applications ls -t      srsly I am soooo frustrated omg