# Problem Creating Desktop Shortcut to Terminal Linux Command

Tags: gnome, shortcuts

`/usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new` is the linux command for creating Desktop shortcuts.

So naturally the first shortcut I need is a short cut to the command:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

When I create the shortcut it will not execute. I am using 18.04 and the text of the shortcut created is below. I have also created it with Terminal attribute set to true but that also sits there and does nothing. I have also tried placing the command inside a bash shell script and making sure everything is executable. Nothing works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_US]=CreateLauncher
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
Name=CreateLauncher
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

Comment: What's the full output of the `gnome-desktop-item-edit` command you're trying to run, when you run it in a terminal? Does it wait for input, or finish immediately?

Comment: It throws up a little dialog box that asks for the shortcut deatails.

Comment: I have done this before in past ubuntu versions from a few years ago. I am an Ubuntu prodigal son. Creating a shortcut to the shortcut command is one of my first acts of business when I create an Ubuntu instance...

Comment: Hmm, seems like it should run then. Maybe the gnome-desktop-item-edit doesn't like to run non-interactively. Could verify the first shortcut is even working, change the Exec line to something noticeable, like play a sound or `zenity --warning --text="Test desktop"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do this with the below way..

1. create a script named `cl.sh` on Desktop to run the command `/usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new` with below content.

   Content of the script

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   /usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
   ```
2. `cd ~/Desktop`
3. Make the script executable with `chmod a+x cl.sh`
4. Open the "Create Launcher" with `./cl.sh`
   A dialog "**Create Launcher**" will pop up.
5. Give the command as `/home/user/Desktop/cl.sh` Replace `user` with your username
6. Click the Icon on Desktop and click trust and launch.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I am trying to do. When I put the /usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new in a shell script like you did the resulting shortcut raises a launch error. If I put the /usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new command directly in the shortcut it doesn't do anything.

Comment: the shell script runs fine from the command line. Also the other test that you suggested worked:

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_US]=Test
Exec=zenity --warning --text="Test desktop"
Name=Test
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Just curious, what ubuntu version did you do this in? In 18.04 it only worked with the full path to desktop folder - /home/{whatever}/Desktop.

Comment: i did it on 18.04 and 18.10 both..

Comment: I just tried it your way and it worked this time. I guess the deal is that if the commands are executed within the context of the environment of a shell script the absolute paths are resolved. The Exec functionality, by itself, has no context...

Answer (score 1):

It seems the error lies in `Exec` value. Desktop entries need absolute paths. So, replace `~/Desktop/` with `/home/username/Desktop/` such that value of `Exec` in desktop entry looks like:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit /home/username/Desktop/ --create-new
```

**Explanation:**

From [Desktop Entry Specification -](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)

> The `Exec` key must contain a command line. A command line consists of an executable program optionally followed by one or more arguments. The executable program can either be specified with its **full path** or with the name of the executable only. If no full path is provided the executable is looked up in the `$PATH` environment variable used by the desktop environment. The name or path of the executable program may not contain the equal sign ("="). Arguments are separated by a space.

Comment: @blogman This isn't a bug but it is doing what it is intended to do. I've updated my answer to include explanation.

Comment: The original command line "/usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new" that uses the absolute path to the desktop folder has been documented for a long time and I am pretty sure that I was able to use it as is in a shortcut in past Ubuntu versions. So I was mistaken to say the bug is in the gnome-desktop-item-edit command. Rather the bug would be in the operating system's failure to expand the absolute path prior to executing the command.

Comment: As an example execute the command zenity --warning --text=$HOME from the command line and then from a shortcut either with Terminal set to True or False. In the latter case the dialog box displays "$HOME" rather than the value of the $HOME environment variable. Shouldn't their be some expectation of the short cut exec functionality being able to pick up the environment when parsing command lines? It is capable of finding the command itself in the path because the full path to the command being executed needn't be provided.

Comment: Here is another example but it only runs sometimes:

#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_US]=Testecho
Exec=echo $HOME
Name=Testecho
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher

Comment: The absolute paths work within a shell script

Comment: @blogman There is a difference in shell script and Desktop Entry. As I said earlier this isn't a bug but it is supposed to be like this. If you remember that Ubuntu version where `$HOME` or tilde(`~`), let me know that. I'll try to test on that also. According to [Jacob's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/722182/816190): *In a `.desktop` file, you need to use absolute and full paths. Therefore `~` is not expanded.* If you have any further doubts you can always ask a new question. May be someone could post a well explanatory answer there. Thanks :)

Comment: I am not confusing shell scripts and desktop entries. My point is that a desktop entry that executes a shell script will work when the absolute paths are referenced in the shell script and not referenced directly in execute attribute of the desktop entry. It works that it is what I am using after implementing PRATAP's solution. See above. It works

Comment: @blogman I see in PRATAP's answer, desktop entry was just used to call the script and there too **full path of script** was used in Exec's value. Desktop entry just called the script and everything else was handled by script. Scripts seem to expand `~` as home. So, all work is done by script, desktop entry created *just another way* to launch the script.