# Why does Google Chrome icon show some other name in Linux?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome icon shows some other name on its shortcut. It shows the name of some Chrome Extension. Why is this the case and how to resolve it?

This is the image:

[image: App icon]

Comment: Probably desktop entry for Screen Recorder is malformed and contains Chrome's icon in `Icon` meta. What is the output of `grep -iR -A6 ~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: I hope it is safe to do this? The current output is "grep: .gvfs: Permission denied", and after that the program is still running. Should I run it with super user permissions?

Comment: Damn!! I missed the pattern to be searched. It should be `grep -iR -A6 "Screen Recorder" ~/.local/share/applications`. Don't use superuser/root account in any case.

Comment: The output is something like the following:
google-chrome.desktop:Name=Screen Recorder - Scre.io
google-chrome.desktop-Icon=google-chrome
google-chrome.desktop-Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome --enable-crashpad
Followed by some more lines...

Comment: There you go. `Icon` meta has `google-chrome` as the value and thus the problem. You can simply edit that .desktop file with any text editor like nano, vim or even gedit to change values. See https://askubuntu.com/q/722179. After changing values, reload the shell.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/367243

Comment: How did this automatically get changed in the first place?