# .desktop icon created but refuses to appear in Gnome desktop

Tags: 20.04, icons, .desktop, favorites

I installed gns3 with dpkg, and was able to add a fav icon. Later I found out I needed to uninstall gns3 and install an older version.
I was able to uninstall the dpkg version and install the older version. I added the older version to my path and am able to execute it directly from terminal and it works. However I am not able to add a fav icon.

After I installed the version I needed I checked in `~/.local/share/applications` and found a `gns3.desktop` file. I cant tell if this was from the first version I installed with dpkg, or the older version I installed after.

Either way, this Icon refuses to show up when I search in the `Show Applications` button. It does not show in my fav either.

Here is what the file looks like

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=gns3 %f
Name=GNS3
Comment=GNS3 Graphical Network Simulator
Icon=gns3
Categories=Education;Network;
MimeType=application/x-gns3;application/x-gns3appliance;application/x-gns3project;
Keywords=simulator;network;netsim;
```

I have not changed anything yet on it, I am more curious why it does not show up. Do I need to refresh something on Ubuntu for it to appear? "gns3" IS in my path, and I can reach it. I also tried copying this file to `/usr/share/applications`, but still it refuses to show up

Why can I not see this icon?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome.

Comment: where is the icon file located? In the same directory as the .desktop?

Comment: No, it appears to be in ~/.local/share/icon/hicolor, there are a varity of png and svg icons in here. Would the `gns3.desktop` file not being able to find the icon be the problem?

Comment: yes, you should use the full path to the icon. You can also do `desktop-file-install <filename>`, which will check the file for validity and copy it to the correct place, and display errors if something is wrong.

Comment: hmm, Id rather not put full path names for two reasons. 1) Looking at other .desktop files in /usr/share/applications (like firefox.desktop) shows `Icon=firefox`. 2) I dont know which .png or .svg to use for the icon. How does `firefox.desktop` able to have it's own icon and not pointing to a direct path? How can I enable the same for my gns3.desktop file?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/435603/desktop-files-how-to-specify-the-icon-path , also https://askubuntu.com/questions/722179/icon-path-in-desktop-file

Comment: What is the output of `which gns3`?